# ion-router-outlet not showing component but router-outlet does

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, routes, components

I'm experimenting with ionic and angular routing and have encountered some issues.
I have two components, first and second, and the app-root component.

app.component.html:

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-title>Router App</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-title>Click To Navigate</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        <a routerLink="first-component" routerLinkActive="active"><ion-button>First</ion-button></a>
        <a routerLink="second-component" routerLinkActive="active"><ion-button>Second</ion-button></a>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-content>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-card>
  
</ion-app>
```

and app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FirstComponent } from './first/first.component';
import { SecondComponent } from './second/second.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'first-component', component: FirstComponent },
  { path: 'second-component', component: SecondComponent },
  { path: 'home-component', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The two components are simply

```
<p>componentName works!</p>
```

Now the issue I've got is the  doesn't work and displays nothing when I click on the buttons to show the component.
But, if I use the normal angular  the components display at the very bottom of the page, leaving a big gap in the middle.

I'm quite new to Angular and this is my second day playing around with Ionic so I'm not too sure where I've gone wrong.

Let me know if any additional info is missing and I'll add it on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is not where you think. Here is how to use cards : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/card
You can't have an `<ion-card>` without `<ion-card-content>`. Do you realy need a card there ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to route like this. This is ionic default way.
[image]